# Model X and Model Y each has_many Z, :dependent => :destroy. If I destroy X, does Z get destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have:

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :z, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Y < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :z, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Z < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :x
  belongs_to :y
end
```

... and then I:

```
x.destroy
```

Does `z` get destroyed if it also belongs to `y`?

I know it's pretty simple to test and I'll do so and answer my own question if I don't get any responses, but in addition to the correct answer I'm also interested in better knowing how :dependent => :destroy works and if there are any other implications I need to be aware of. The ActiveRecord::Base documentation is pretty sparse on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will for sure destroy all z objects connected, and that will make a lot of business errors on your database.

IMHO I would refactor this modeling. Work with this kind of relationship could go terribly bad. Is there a reason you can't remodel?

Maybe if just change the validation could work, or even make X and Y inherit some ohter class that makes the relationhip with the X class.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but I would assume that `z` would get destroyed regardless of it's association to `y`.

As for implications... `:destroy` will first instantiate each instance of `z` and call `:destroy` on it.  Should that fail due to validations/hooks on `z` then the original `x` will fail to be destroyed.

Also, if `x` has thousands and thousands of `z's` it can take some time, at which point `:delete_all` might be better.